# How to replace two or more consecutive double quotes?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, double-quotes

For the strings like:

```
""abc"""
```

It should be:

```
"abc"
```

But my attempt is failing by using:

```
preg_replace('/[\"]+/','"',$input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work...

```
$input = '""abs"""';
//$input = '""abs""';
//$input = '"abs"""';
//$input = '""abs""';
$input = preg_replace('/"+/','"',$input);

echo $input;
```

Short explanation of the regular expression -

- `"` - this is the character we are looking for.
- `+` - the plus sign indicates that we are looking for **one or more** of the previously mentioned characters...

<sub>My answer builds on [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540576/how-to-replace-two-or-more-consecutive-double-quotes/11540642#11540642) by [@joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey) that has since been removed...</sub>

---

References -

- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Who ever deleted their answer here please make your self known so that I can attribute some credit to you for this answer...